# Entrada e saída de dados em Java e tratamento dos dados

Tags: java, io

Possuo uma lista gigante de exercícios e fiquei apenas com esses dois por último para fazer mas não consigo de JEITO NENHUM. Essa parada de I/O não entrou na minha cabeça nem por reza braba!

39. Faça um programa que leia um arquivo texto, nomeado “entrada.txt”, composto por valores inteiros e gere um arquivo texto, nomeado “saída.txt”, contendo somente os números primos do arquivo de entrada.
40. Faça um programa que leia o arquivo texto gerado pelo programa anterior, “saída.txt”, e verifique e imprima em tela, o maior número presente no arquivo e a quantidade de números do arquivo que são maiores do que a média de valores contidos no arquivo.

Se alguém puder por gentileza me explicar como faço isso, fico grato! Fiz todos os outros exercícios e gostaria de tirar a nota máxima fazendo todos.

Isso é o que tenho de código da questão 1 até agora:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class trab2{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            System.out.println("edite o arquivo entrada.txt");

            File entrada = new File("entrada.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(entrada);
            PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter("saida.txt");

            boolean ehPrimo = true;
            int contador = 2;
            while(in.hasNextInt()){
                int valor = in.nextInt();
                while(contador < valor){                    
                    if(valor % contador == 0){
                        ehPrimo = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    contador++;

                }
                    saida.println(valor);
            }
            saida.close();
            in.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado. Tente novamente.");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Erro de execução: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Da questão dois, o que consegui fazer é isso:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class dois{
public static void main(String [] args){
    int acumulador = 0;
            try{
        File saida = new File("saida.txt");
        Scanner insaida = new Scanner(saida);
        while(insaida.hasNextInt()){            
        int valor = insaida.nextInt();    
        if(valor > acumulador){acumulador = valor;}
        }

        System.out.println("O maior valor no arquivo saida.txt é: " +acumulador);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado. Tente novamente.");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Erro de execução: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

o que não consigo fazer é a média dos valores inseridos no arquivo, e como saber quantos números tem no arquivo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para a questão 39, você tinha apenas pequenos erros no seu código, veja nos comentários no próprio código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Teste{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            System.out.println("edite o arquivo entrada.txt");

            File entrada = new File("entrada.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(entrada);
            PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter("saida.txt");

            while(in.hasNextInt()){
                //esse valor tem que virar true a cada iteração
                boolean ehPrimo = true; 

                //ele também deve ser resetado para 2 a cada iteração
                int contador = 2;

                int valor = in.nextInt();
                //uma otimização simples é testar o contador até a metade do valor
                //pois nunca um número dividido por outro que seja maior que a sua
                //metade dará resto 0
                while(contador <= valor/2){                    
                    if(valor % contador == 0){
                        ehPrimo = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    contador++;
                }
                //tem que ter o if aqui para se certificar de que ele passou no teste
                if(ehPrimo) {           
                    saida.println(valor);
                }
            }
            saida.close();
            in.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado. Tente novamente.");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Erro de execução: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Para a questão 40:

> o maior número presente no arquivo

você precisa definir uma variável com o menor valor possível, por exemplo:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

E iterar sobre todos os itens do seu arquivo de texto, sempre que o arquivo da iteração atual for maior do que o valor contido em `max`, você atribui ao `max` esse novo valor:

> e a quantidade de números do arquivo que são maiores do que a média de valores contidos no arquivo.

Antes de mais nada você precisa tirar a média. Acredito que o melhor éiterar item por item e ir somando a quantidade de itens percorridos e a soma do valor deles. Depois então você começa a iteração de novo desde o início, verificando quantos valores são maiores do que a média.